# Last Transaction of each day

Tags: python, pandas

```
Sales Invoice   02-01-21 10:52
Invoice 02-01-21 10:55
Sales Invoice   02-01-21 11:54
Invoice 02-01-21 12:18
 Dev Invoice    02-01-21 12:37
 Dev Invoice    02-01-21 12:41
Sales Invoice   02-01-21 13:32
Sales Invoice   03-01-21 11:50
 Dev Invoice    03-01-21 13:37
 Dev Invoice    03-01-21 13:42
Invoice 03-01-21 13:57
Sales Invoice   03-01-21 14:50
Invoice 04-01-21 9:39
 Dev Invoice    04-01-21 9:40
Sales Invoice   04-01-21 10:04
Sales Invoice   04-01-21 11:52
Sales Invoice   04-01-21 12:35
 Dev Invoice    04-01-21 13:11
Sales Invoice   04-01-21 14:04
Sales Invoice   04-01-21 14:40
Sales Invoice   04-01-21 15:49
Sales Invoice   04-01-21 16:24
Sales Invoice   05-01-21 9:21
Invoice 05-01-21 10:15
Sales Invoice   05-01-21 10:53
Invoice 05-01-21 10:55
Sales Invoice   05-01-21 10:58
Invoice 05-01-21 12:32
Invoice 05-01-21 12:37
 Dev Invoice    05-01-21 13:01
Invoice 05-01-21 13:57
Sales Invoice   05-01-21 14:47
Sales Invoice   05-01-21 16:23
Invoice       05-01-21 16:54
 Dev Invoice    06-01-21 10:55
Sales Invoice   06-01-21 11:04
Sales Invoice   06-01-21 12:43
Sales Invoice   01-02-21 9:29
Sales Invoice   01-02-21 9:40
```

i have Data set as above and i want to extract the last Transact for each day,the data has transactions for a year
i used the below code

```
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\TransactionsByTenderTypeCSV.csv")
df['DateCreated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateCreated'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')

df.sort_values(by ='DateCreated',ascending=True).apply
   
dfFandL=df.groupby(df['DateCreated'].dt.date).apply(lambda x: x.iloc[np.r_[:,-1:0]])
```

but for Some reason the code only works for the 1st 4 months of data and the last 3 months ,some times it does not give the correct last transaction

Comment: Is this line a typo `df.sort_values(by ='DateCreated',ascending=True).apply`? because first if you don't reassign the `sort_values`, then df is still not sorted after. then why the `apply` here?

Comment: thank you i think this was part of the problem

Answer (score 0):

When i run you code I get an error because it seems the formatting in the `to_datetime` function is not coherent with your data. To read it correctly I had to use this:

```
df['DateCreated'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateCreated'], format='%d-%m-%y %H:%M')
```

Nevertheless, I would change approach and separate the date from the time:

```
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateCreated']).dt.date
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateCreated']).dt.time
df.groupby('Dates').max()
```